# GCM - Google cloud messaging: Connection closed when ccs client logins

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I created my Project Number, API key, registration ID and implemented a http server sucessfullly, but when implement css(xmpp) server, it doesn't work. I use the tutorial for java in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

the console displays red alert:

```
INFO: Loading providers for file [classpath:META-INF/extension.providers]
SASL authentication PLAIN failed: text: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:342)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:243)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:368)
    at server.SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:334)
    at server.SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:344)
Apr 16, 2014 3:48:29 PM server.SmackCcsClient$2 connectionClosed
INFO: Connection closed.
```

line 334 is:

> connection.login(username, password);

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same Error when I tried to implement XMPP(CCS).So after going through so many site I found that  to use up streaming feature of GCM (XMPP) you need to register for this service as a trail partner.

they are saying something like this

> After you have created your GCM enabled project in the API Console you must fill out this form and become a trial partner to use upstream messaging and user notifications via CCS. Access is limited to those that fill out the form. You will receive an email from Google informing you that you now have access; Google will also send you the address of an echo server that you can use to bounce messages back to your application.

so visit this site and fill form

[Upstream Google Cloud Messaging and User Notifications Sign-up](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/)

**Update**

Now up-streaming using GCM(CCS) is open for all developers !!!

Comment: I filled this form, but just received an email from noreply@google.com with content: "Thank you. Your information has been sent to Google. A member of the team will be in touch shortly"
I chose Active Mobile Users: 1M-5M

Comment: That's great,I got conformation mail from Google after a week of submitting form.hope you will also get reply from them soon...